# Navigation Bar Hidden on Rotation When Keyboard Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, keyboard, screen-rotation

I have a webview in my application.  When the user brings up the keyboard to type into a text field and then rotates the screen the navigation bar scrolls up the screen as well as the text field in question, obscuring the status bar.  Not only that but the screen auto scrolls back to that default position when you try to scroll up in the web view.

Any help on fixing this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Are you correctly adding constraints?

Comment: I would be very surprised to find that it's a constraints issue.  I have no other constraints anywhere else in the app.